# Setting up an Excel volume calculator

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently in the process of creating an excel volume calculator to help estimate item volume in a home, the problem is I need the sheet to perform individual multiplications, store the value, then sum them all up at the end.

I need the sheet to mulitply the No col by the M3, and store this in the sum, but the sheet has around 200 items so instead of doing each one manually like =sum (A1*B1 + A2*B2 + A3*B3 etc etc) I wondered if there was an easier way?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSxU1.png)

Comment: Try this formula `=SumProduct(A:A,B:B)`

Comment: You could use `SUMPRODUCT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a new column, say column **X**, with the formula =A1*B1 and fill the series for each row. So every cell in that column will be A1*B1, A2*B2,A3*B3, etc.

Now set a new column, say column **Y**, to =sum(X1:X_?_) where the question mark is the last row you would like to sum.

That will give you your desired A1*B2 + A2*B2, etc.